# Terraform safeguards

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have already dozens of AWS instances running on production, and I would like to start using Terraform to automate the next ones creation. I have read that Terraform can help practicing Immutable pattern. However I would like to avoid any risk to destroy any already running instance. Does Terraform provide any protection to avoid this ?

Answer (score 1):

Yep - use [`terraform plan`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html) before any operation. It will output a full list of changes that'll be made, wihtout actually *executing* any of them, for your review.

Answer (score 1):

Terraform has no explicit safeguards for this, but its general design already prevents it from touching existing resources.

Generally every Terraform resource has some primary identifier (e.g. for EC2 an instance ID, for S3 a bucket name). And every Terraform run should only a) create new resources or b) update/delete existing resources under Terraform control.

- In case a) if the ID already exists, then you get an error and Terraform cannot create anything (will never happen with EC2, but is possible with S3 buckets). This is the opportunity to fix the Terraform code.
- In case b) Terraform should only work with "its own" resources, leaving the existing content of your account alone.

One can intentionally (or accidentally) interfere with Terraform  by replacing/renaming its resources, that will break things; but with "normal" use I have never seen these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a lifecycle configuration block to the resource ([See Terraform Resource Configuration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html)); specifically by using:

```
lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
}
```

This will return an error message when a plan includes a destroy action on the resource.